# Reemplazar cadenas manteniendo la mayúscula-minúscula

Tags: python

Me gustaría hacer un programa en `Python` que reemplace una `subcadena` dentro de una `cadena`, manteniendo la `minúscula-mayúscula`.

Por ejemplo:

- Jirafa -> León
- JiRaFa -> LeÓn
- jiRaFa -> leÓn

etc. ¿Es posible hacer esto?

Comment: Please, traduce la pregunta. Quizás no te diste cuenta, pero estás preguntando en Stack Overflow en Español. De paso aclara un poco a qué te refieres con "manteniendo el caso". Supongo que es respetar el orden Mayus-minus-Mayus-Mayus-minus... de la primera cadena cuando la cambias por la segunda. ¿Qué ocurre si la primera es más corta?

Comment: @abulafia Perdón. Si, me refiero a eso. En cuanto a lo de si la primera palabra es más corta, se podría repetir el orden desde el principio, o simplemente dejar en minúscula el resto, si la primera opción no es muy viable. Aunque en mi caso la primera palabra va a ser más larga que la segunda, así que eso no sería un problema.

Comment: Y quieres que todo ello funcione como una especie de `replace()`, es decir, tienes una cadena larga, en la que buscas otra más corta para reemplazar esta última? Por ejemplo `mi_replace("Esto es una PrUEbA", "prueba", "cosa")` para generar como resultado `"Esto es una CoSA"` ? Y de ser asi ¿puede aparecer varias veces "prueba" en la cadena y deben reemplazarse todas?

Comment: @abulafia Exactamente. Puede aparecer varias veces.

Comment: Jo*er @abufalia, qué capacidad de comprensión y deducción!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La siguiente función hace (creo) lo que pides. No me pidas que te la explique :-) Es muy farragosa, no estoy nada orgulloso de ella. Además sólo funciona si la cadena que buscas es más larga que la que la va a sustituir.

```
def replace_with_case(cadena, sub, repl):
  result = []
  i = cadena.lower().find(sub.lower())
  while i != -1 and cadena:
      result.append(cadena[:i])
      palabra = []
      cadena = cadena[i:]
      for j, letra in enumerate(repl):
        if cadena[j].islower():
          palabra.append(letra.lower())
        elif cadena[j].isupper():
          palabra.append(letra.upper())
        else:
          palabra.append(letra)
      result.append("".join(palabra))
      cadena = cadena[len(sub):]
      i = cadena.lower().find(sub.lower())
  result.append(cadena)
  return "".join(result)
```

Aunque no tengo ahora tiempo para explicarla, puedes preguntar en comentarios cualquier detalle que necesites saber, y responderé en cuanto pueda.

Algunos ejemplos de uso:

```
print(replace_with_case(
    "Esto es una PrUEbA, la palabra prUeba aparece varias veces", 
    "prueba", "cosa"))
print(replace_with_case(
    "Aqui PRUeba sólo aparece una vez", 
    "prueba", "cosa"))
print(replace_with_case(
    "Aqui no aparece ninguna vez", 
    "prueba", "cosa"))
print(replace_with_case(
    "prueba PRUEBA pRUEBA Prueba PRueba PrUeBa", 
    "prueba", "cosa"))
print(replace_with_case(
    "ra:ro RA:ro RA:RO rA:rO ra:RO", 
    "ra:ro", "al.go"))
```

Resultado:

```html
Esto es una CoSA, la palabra coSa aparece varias veces
Aqui COSa sólo aparece una vez
Aqui no aparece ninguna vez
cosa COSA cOSA Cosa COsa CoSa
al.go AL.go AL.GO aL.gO al.GO
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias!